# Threads in eXist-db/XQuery

Tags: multithreading, rest, thread-safety, xquery, exist-db

I impement a webbased database application with eXist-db by using the restxq module. Within this application projects are managed.
Now I want to make the creating and editing processes of a project thread safe. Did not really found something in the eXist literature and in the web so I would like to ask you here if there are solutions in eXist/XQuery.

Best regards,
Felix

Comment: Hi Felix, For this type of question I'd suggest you pose it to exist-open. (See https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/exist-open for subscription info if you haven't already subscribed.)

Comment: Hi joewiz, I asked this question by sending an email to the sourceforge list of eXist, too, but neither in this nor in another earlier case I got an answer from anybody :-/

Comment: Hi Felix, you need to subscribe to exist-open otherwise your posts are blocked and held in a queue

Comment: For anyone who finds this thread, the discussion has continued on exist-open; see at http://markmail.org/message/txx5w7m4cbwkodbq.